# Resize ImageView even if ScaleType

Tags: android, resize, imageview, layoutparams, scaletype

I have a problem, I'm trying to resize a `ImageView` and its parent container but the problem is that the `ImageView` has `ScaleType:"matrix"`, and I cant`t resize the image or its container
this is my code:

```
public void resize() {

    LayoutParams contet = relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
    LayoutParams photo =  image.getLayoutParams();


    int widPhoto = image.getWidth();
    int hePhoto = image.getHeight();

    photo.width = ((widPhoto * 6) / 2);
    photo.height = ((hePhoto * 6) / 2);

    contenedor.width = widPhoto * 2;
    contenedor.height = hePhoto * 2;


    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(contenedor); 

    image.setLayoutParams(photo );
}
```

and my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`setLayoutParams()` does nothing but remove the property `ScaleType` if I resize everything correctly, but I cant´t remove that property. Any way to resize? they could put the property `ScaleType: NONE`? thank you very much and sorry for my bad English

Comment: no, look this example, my Drag and Drop is this http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, if you are using the `Layout ScaleType: matrix`
you need to use `matrix.setScale ();` for Resizing

Answer (score 0):

To resize your ImageView, I suggest to use FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fm_id"
    android:layout_width="img_width"
    android:layout_height="img_height"
    ... ...

    >
   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:gravity="center"
     />

</FrameLayout>
```

then you just need to resize 'img_width' and 'img_height' in your codes

Comment: The problem is scaleType not FrameLayout